# Foreach or While -- Best for processing array?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

So what I am trying to do is process an array. The array contains one thing: photo urls.

When I use foreach()I get a limit error (500 internal error). It seems that it started happening after I rewrote the script. But that doesnt make any sense as there are no errors in the script and it was working perfectly before. The script still works, it can only process about 30 photos before the error pops up. Is it possible to use while() to process the array? Would it get rid of my 500 error for some reason?

Thanks for the input!
Brandon

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: The 500 error comes from the web server, not the PHP interpreter.  If you check your web server's error log for the site, PHP may have added a more descriptive error there.  Also, show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting timeout (infinite loops) errors, neither while or foreach will do. You're better off looking at limiting how much your array is processed, and do it step by step (Pagination..?).

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    //Do your thing. Don't use for each, use $array[$i]
}
```

if it's not numeric, use a while with two statements:

```
while ($test = current($array) && $i < 50)
{
     //xxxx
     next($array);
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance is better foreach cycle.
Visit this site with some benchmark of php and see which cycle is better for you:
http://www.phpbench.com/